# ApplicaionBar shows black background while hiding or showing

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

The problem is that when my device's theme is set to dark there comes a black background during animation of showing and hiding of `ApplicationBar`. I either want white or none in background.

[Here is a video that shows it](http://youtu.be/7LfVbB-4i7Y)

My XAML file

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="AppBarTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar Mode="Default" Opacity="1.0" IsMenuEnabled="False" IsVisible="True" BackgroundColor="#AAAAAA" ForegroundColor="Black">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/add.png" Text="add"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/delete.png" Text="delete"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/feature.camera.png" Text="camera"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Button Content="Hide/Show" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="Green" Click="Button_Click" Margin="112,66,122,0" Height="150" Width="246"/>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And my CS file

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = !ApplicationBar.IsVisible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is due to the ApplicationBar not actually being part of the page but actually being part of the shell.

When the ApplicationBar is included it adjusts the size of the space available to the app. Your page does not therefore occupy the space that was behind the ApplicationBar and so the default background colour shows through.

The simplest way to change this is to not have an opaque ApplicationBar. By adding a level of transparency (even 1%) to the ApplicationBar it is displayed on top of your page, not below it.
This will address your issue when hiding the ApplicationBar but you will now need to handle content being displayed behind it.

Comment: Lol it worked. And good explanation just set `Opacity="0.99"`. Would love to give you 100 up-votes if I could :)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore you could always find some of my other answers and upvote them ;) http://stackoverflow.com/users/1755/matt-lacey?tab=answers